# Spring Boot: use several locale message.properties for logging depending on 'args' value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am kind of new in spring boot. I want to setup my spring boot aplication to choose a specific locale messages.properties file when a specific arg is used when starting the program. These message.properties fields will be used to log program events and also for sending out email reports to customers.

The examples I found are only suitable for web applications. And I couldn't find any suitable examples on how this can be achieved by using inbuilt spring boot technology.

Comment: Do you mean you want to choose which language to fetch messages for, or do you mean you want to pick a completely different resource bundle (so `error_messages.properties` rather than `messages.properties`, for example)?

Comment: I want to have two different language files: messages_en.properties and messages_de.properties. and fet a specific one depending upon the arg value

Comment: Then I believe Miloš Milivojević's answer should do the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, regular Spring Boot is just an application run from the `main()` method - you can set the default Locale via `Locale.setDefault` method before you run your Spring application, like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale defaultLocale = determineLocaleFrom(args);
    Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);

    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    MessageSource messageSource = context.getBean(MessageSource.class);
    // when fetching messages, always read from the default locale
    messageSource.getMessage("my.message.code", null, Locale.getDefault());
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I keep getting this error: Caused by: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'field1' for locale 'en_US'.

Comment: I think the error is indicative enough - you either don't have the appropriate `messages.properties` file or you don't have the correct message present

Comment: the correct file is there: messages_en_US.properties and the field is there

Comment: You do have the `messages.properties` file, too? Without it, auto-configuration will not be triggered.